# Add up the values of multiple occurrences of multiple strings in a multidimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I've got a multidimensional array.

I need a way to tally up the total value when both the 1st and second strings in the array occur multiple times.

So for instance : 
Gold Metallic = 22
Black Toscano = 26

etc...

Any ideas?

```
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Black
                    [1] => Toscano
                    [2] => 14
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Gold
                    [1] => Metallic
                    [2] => 10
                )

        )

     [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Gold
                    [1] => Metallic
                    [2] => 12
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Black
                    [1] => Toscano
                    [2] => 12
                )

        )
```

Comment: I've tried using in_array to search for the specific strings but i'm going to potentially have dozens of combinations so this likely won't be efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be a simple case of looping over the data and storing an array of sums. This is one possibility using a hash with keys as the pairs concatenated with a separator sentinel value.

```
$separator = "||"; //take care to choose something that doesn't pop up in your data here
//$data = example data;
$pairs = array();

foreach ($data as $val) {
    foreach ($val as $pair) {
        $str = $pair[0] . $separator . $pair[1];
        if (array_key_exists($str, $pairs))
            $pairs[$str] += $pair[2];
        else
            $pairs[$str] = $pair[2];
    }
}

print_r($pairs);

output:

["Black||Toscano"] => 26,
["Gold||Metallic"] => 22
```

The data can be easily retrieved at this point

```
foreach ($pairs as $str => $sum) {
    $str = explode($separator, $str);
    echo $str[0] . ", " . $str[1] . ": " . $sum;
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed to get me going in the right direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This just solves the problem for your data structure so you have to make sure that, in practice, every two items you will get a number. Hope you can learn something from this :)

```
$products = array(
    array(
        array("Black", "Toscano", 14),
        array("Gold", "Metallic", 10)
    ),
    array(
        array("Black", "Toscano", 12),
        array("Gold", "Metallic", 12)
    ),
);


$accumulated = array();
$key = "";

$callback = function($item, $index) use(&$key, &$accumulated) {
    if($index != 2) {
        $key .= $item;
    } else {
        if(!array_key_exists($key, $accumulated)) {
            $accumulated[$key] = 0;
        }
        $accumulated[$key] += $item;
        $key = "";
    }
};

array_walk_recursive($products, $callback);
var_dump($accumulated);
```